# Understanding where the link function is computed in Poisson regression

Tags: r, glm, poisson

From [Poisson Regression by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922656/poisson-regression-by-hand) this 'manual' Poisson coefficient function is provided:

```
LogLike <- function(y,x, par) {
  beta <- par
  # the deterministic part of the model:
  lambda <- exp(beta%*%t(x))
  # and here comes the negative log-likelihood of the whole dataset, given     the
  # model:
  LL <- -sum(dpois(y, lambda, log = TRUE))
  return(LL)
}


PoisMod<-function(formula, data){

  # # definiere Regressionsformel
  form <- formula(formula)
  # 
  # # dataFrame wird erzeugt 
   model <- model.frame(formula, data = data)
  # 
  # # Designmatrix erzeugt
  x <- model.matrix(formula,data = data)
  # 
  # # Response Variable erzeugt
   y <- model.response(model)

  par <- rep(0,ncol(x))
  erg <- list(optim(par=par,fn=LogLike,x=x,y=y)$par)
  return(erg)
}

PoisMod(breaks~wool+tension, as.data.frame(daten))
glm(breaks~wool+tension, family = "poisson", data = as.data.frame(daten))
```

Can any one tell me exactly where the link function is computed here? What would this code look like with an identity link function? I have basic understanding from YouTube videos etc, but no one explains the actual computation.

How would this code look like with offset and weights?

Comment: in the `dpois()` function there is the argument `log=TRUE`. Normally Poisson GLMs use the log link function, so I believe an identity link function could be achieved by setting `log=FALSE` in the `dpois()` call

Comment: The `log=TRUE` in the `dpois()` function simply produces individual log-likelihoods instead of likelihoods. Where the link function comes in is `exp(beta %*% t(x))` the inverse of the log link is `exp()`.  If you were using an identity link, you would have `lambda = beta %*% t(x)`

Comment: thank you so much! This really makes is easier to understand. I have a follow up question on weights and offsets. Maybe you are able to simply explain this aswell?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, please post your comment as an answer ...

Answer (score 2):

The GLM is specified as:

[image]

or equivalently as

[image]

In the case of the Poisson model, the canonical link is [image], so [image]

You can see that in your code where `lambda = exp(beta %*% t(x))` If you wanted to estimate a model with an identity link, you would use `lambda = beta %*% t(x)` because in that case [image]

Addressing the follow-up questions in the comments, with weights, often these are used to weight the likelihood contribution for each observation.  So, imagine you had a variable `wt` that you passed into your function `LogLike()`, you could modify it by multiplying the likelihood contribution by the weight:

```
LL <- -sum(dpois(y, lambda, log = TRUE)*wt)
```

An offset is just a variable whose coefficient is forced to be 1 (see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175349/in-a-poisson-model-what-is-the-difference-between-using-time-as-a-covariate-or) for a discussion).  Lets say you had a variable called `offset` that you wanted to include in your model.  Again, you could pass that argument to `LogLike()` and you would need to modify the function by:

```
  lambda <- exp(beta%*%t(x) + offset)
```

Following the example in the CrossValidated post I linked, `offset = log(time)`.  Which offset is correct is more of a theoretical or substantive matter.

Comment: Thank you so much! The details in GLM is so much easier to understand with code example. I'm sure many other students like me will appreciate this post.